# React - unable to load component within another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I'm new to React JS scripting and this is my first code. This code is part of the parent component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showComponent: false,
    };
    this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);
}

_onButtonClick() {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for='dropdown1'>Dropdown Label: </label></td>
                    <td>
                        <Dropdown id='dropdown1'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Default value'></input>
                            <DropdownMenu id='dropdownmenu1'>
                                <DropdownItem id='dropdownitem1'>Item 1</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu>
                        </Dropdown>
                    </td>
                    <td><label for='fromDate'>From: </label></td>
                    <td><input type='date' id='fromDate'></input></td>
                    <td><label for='toDate'>To: </label></td>
                    <td><input type='date' id='toDate'></input></td>
                    <td><input type='dropdown' id='dropdown2'></input></td>
                    <td>
                        <Button id="btn" onClick = {this._onButtonClick}>Fetch Details</Button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr width="500px">
                        <td>              
                            {this.state.showComponent ? <TablePage /> : null}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </h4>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`TablePage` is my expected Child component, which contains `Resize`, `ResizeVertical` and `ResizeHorizon` from `react-resize-layout`, but during runtime, it does not display as part of child component. In fact, it overlaps with the parent component. I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

**UPDATE:** I've added `TablePage` code below and attached the screenshot.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Resize, ResizeVertical, ResizeHorizon } from "react-resize-layout";
import ResizableBox from 'react-resizable-component';
import {BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn} from 'react-bootstrap-table';

const fetchedData = [{
    column1: "Column1",
    column2: "Column2",
    column3: "Column3",
    column4: "Column4",
    column5: "Column5",
    column6: "Column6",
    column7: "Column7",
    column8: "Column8",
    column9: "Column9"
  }, {
    column1: "R2C1",
    column2: "R2C2",
    column3: "R2C3",
    column4: "R2C4",
    column5: "R2C5",
    column6: "R2C6",
    column7: "R2C7",
    column8: "R2C8",
    column9: "R2C9"
  }, {
    column1: "R3C1",
    column2: "R3C2",
    column3: "R3C3",
    column4: "R3C4",
    column5: "R3C5",
    column6: "R3C6",
    column7: "R3C7",
    column8: "R3C8",
    column9: "R3C9"
  }];

class TablePage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>                
                <Resize handleWidth="5px" handleColor="#777">
                            <ResizeVertical height="250px">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>test
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </ResizeVertical>
                            <ResizeVertical height="50px" minHeight="20px">
                                <Resize handleWidth="8px" handleColor="red">
                                    <ResizeHorizon width="150px" height="250px">This section will contain more information...</ResizeHorizon>
                                    <ResizeHorizon width="150px" height="250px">This section will contain graphical information...</ResizeHorizon>
                                </Resize>
                            </ResizeVertical>
                        </Resize>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TablePage;
```

Here are my screenshots-

**Before clicking on "Fetch Details" button**
[image]

**After clicking on "Fetch Details" button**
[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot? it's hard to tell what your problem is.. i think you should post TablePage component as well

Comment: So TablePage is rendering but not its child components?  If that's the case you need to post the TablePage code rather than the parent component.  It is tough to tell exactly what your issue is.

Comment: I have updated the question as mentioned.